# How to parse html output to object in kotlin

Tags: java, json, xml, kotlin

We get response from a service, they are returning the dropdown options list.
I am getting as a string response from api call.

```
<option value="X" title="XXXX">X</option>
<option value="Y" title="YYYY">Y</option>
```

I want to parse this to an array of object something like this in kotlin

```
[
{value:"X",title:"XXXX"},
{value:"Y",title:"YYYY"}
]
```

Can someone help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few solutions. You can parse your simple HTML using regular expression `<option value=\"(.+)\" title=\"(.+)\">.+</option>`

```kotlin
// class to hold parsed result
data class Option(val value: String, val title: String) 

fun main() {
    val html = """
        <option value="X" title="XXXX">X</option>
        <option value="Y" title="YYYY">Y</option>
    """

    val regex = "<option value=\"(.+)\" title=\"(.+)\">.+</option>".toRegex()
    
    val regexOptions = regex.findAll(html)
        .map {
            Option(
                value = it.groupValues[1],
                title = it.groupValues[2]
            )
        }.toList()

    println("RegEx: $regexOptions")
```

or you can use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/) library that is designed to parse complex HTML.

```kotlin
    val jsoupOptions = Jsoup.parse(html)
        .select("option")
        .map {
            Option(
                value = it.attr("value"),
                title = it.attr("title")
            )
        }

    println("Jsoup: $jsoupOptions")
}
```

Output is identical in both cases:

```
RegEx: [Option(value=X, title=XXXX), Option(value=Y, title=YYYY)]
Jsoup: [Option(value=X, title=XXXX), Option(value=Y, title=YYYY)]
```